# mysqli_real_escape_string creating SQL syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax

I am working on a script to update a database when i need to change information on a page, if there are NO special characters in the text (example ' or " ) the script works fine, if there are any special characters I get an error such as this one

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'angry' song, the music will incite surrounding characters to become more aggressive. As' at line 1

I am hoping for help to see what I may have missed in this script, thanks in advance for your time.

Initial Page for selecting data to update

```
<?php
    include('../connect/connect-mysql.php');

$sql="SELECT * FROM table Order by Appeared asc";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
?>
<h4>Update/Edit Tool</h4>

<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td>
<table width="400" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
<tr>
<th align="center"><font face="Verdana" size="1">Update</font></th>
<th align="center"><font face="Verdana" size="1">Power</font></th>
<th align="center"><font face="Verdana" size="1">Power2</font></th>
<th align="center"><font face="Verdana" size="1">Power3</font></th>
<th align="center"><font face="Verdana" size="1">Power4</font></th>
</tr>

<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>

<tr>
<td align="center"><font face="Verdana" size="1"><a href="p_update.php?id=<? echo $rows['IDNumber']; ?>">update</a></font></td>
<td><font face="Verdana" size="1"><div style="height:20px; width:160px; overflow:hidden"><? echo $rows['Power']; ?></div></font></td>
<td><font face="Verdana" size="1"><div style="height:20px; width:160px; overflow:hidden"><? echo $rows['Power2']; ?></div></font></td>
<td><font face="Verdana" size="1"><div style="height:20px; width:160px; overflow:hidden"><? echo $rows['Power3']; ?></div></font></td>
<td><font face="Verdana" size="1"><div style="height:20px; width:160px; overflow:hidden"><? echo $rows['Power4']; ?></div></font></td>
</tr>

<?php
}
?>

</table>
```

Editing page (`p_update.php`) :

```
$id=$_GET['id'];

$sql="SELECT * FROM table WHERE IDNumber='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>
<body>
<h1>Update Data</h1>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="p_update_ac.php">
<fieldset>
    <legend>Update Data</legend>
    <table border="1" width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse">
    <tr><th><font face="Verdana" size="1"><label>Database ID: </label></font></th><td><font size="1" face="Verdana"><input name="IDNumber" type="text" id="IDNumber" value="<?php echo $rows['IDNumber']; ?>" size="10"><b>DO NOT CHANGE THIS FIELD</b></font></td></tr>
    <tr><th><font face="Verdana" size="1"><label>Power Category: </label></font></th><td><font size="1" face="Verdana"><input name="Powcategory" type="text" id="Powcategory" value="<?php echo $rows['Powcategory']; ?>" size="50"></font></td></tr>
    <tr><th><font face="Verdana" size="1"><label>Power: </label></font></th><td><font size="1" face="Verdana"><input name="Power" type="text" id="Power" value="<?php echo $rows['Power']; ?>" size="150"></font></td></tr>
    <tr><th><font face="Verdana" size="1"><label>Power 2: </label></font></th><td><font size="1" face="Verdana"><input name="Power2" type="text" id="Power2" value="<?php echo $rows['Power2']; ?>" size="150"></font></td></tr>
    <tr><th><font face="Verdana" size="1"><label>Power 3: </label></font></th><td><font size="1" face="Verdana"><input name="Power3" type="text" id="Power3" value="<?php echo $rows['Power3']; ?>" size="150"></font></td></tr>
    <tr><th><font face="Verdana" size="1"><label>Power 4: </label></font></th><td><font size="1" face="Verdana"><input name="Power4" type="text" id="Power4" value="<?php echo $rows['Power4']; ?>" size="150"></font></td></tr>
    </table>
</fieldset>
<br>
<input name="id" type="hidden" id="id" value="<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Update Record">
</form>
<?php
// close connection
mysql_close();
?>
```

the following code is `p_update_ac.php` which is called on by the `p_update.php` script in order to run.

```
<?php
include('../connect/connect-mysql.php');

$IDNumber = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $_POST['IDNumber']);
$Power = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $_POST['Power']);
$Power2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $_POST['Power2']);
$Power3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $_POST['Power3']);
$Power4 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $_POST['Power4']);

$sql="UPDATE table SET Power='$Power',Power2='$Power2',Power3='$Power3',Power4='$Power4' WHERE IDNumber='$IDNumber'";
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

if($result){
echo "Successful";
echo "<p>";
echo "<a href='p_list_records.php'>View result</a>";

}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}

?>
```

Comment: Why on Earth do you escape `$IDNumber` twice? )

Comment: Why are you escaping your ID number twice?

Comment: ... that's the first thought that comes to mind, right. ) But there is just too many weirdness here. Why in the first file `$ID...` is not escaped? Why `$_POST[...]` params are not checked for been set? And finally, why no prepared statements? )

Comment: I'm sorry i'm not sure what you mean by 'escape'

Comment: nvm I see what you mean by that, fixed in teh actual script, the script still errors though

Comment: `$IDNumber = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $_POST['IDNumber']);` they mean this, there are 2 mysqli_escape_string so you're escaping twice

Comment: that part is fixed, thanks for pointing it out... the script still produces teh syntax error though if special characters are in the text i'm trying to update.

Comment: You could avoid all this ugliness and error prone code by just using prepared statements! It will make your life easier and safer.

Comment: After reading on wikipedia what a 'Prepared statement'is I am unsure what u mean in regards to this script. Please indulge me as I am still learning. Thx

Comment: Your `p_update_ac.php` isn't working because you're mixing two APIs. @JoJo --- Choose "one"; they don't mix together. I need to see an example of how you're connecting to DB.

Comment: @JoJo You have a possible attack vector in your `p_update.php` file. You are inserting plain value of `$_GET['id'];` and thus it is subject to SQL Injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `UPDATE` code won't work because you are mixing two different APIs, and they do not mix together.

By APIs I mean `mysqli_*` and `mysql_*` functions.

I'm under the impression that your DB connection is in fact `mysql_*` because you wouldn't have gotten an error message otherwise, so I'm including two versions below, just in case (See footnotes):

Sidenote: You should be using `mysqli_*` functions with prepared statements or PDO.

Use the following if `mysql`

```
<?php
include('../connect/connect-mysql.php');

$IDNumber = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['IDNumber']);
$Power = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Power']);
$Power2 = mysql_real_escape_string(_POST['Power2']);
$Power3 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Power3']);
$Power4 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Power4']);

$sql="UPDATE table SET Power='$Power',Power2='$Power2',Power3='$Power3',Power4='$Power4' WHERE IDNumber='$IDNumber'";
$result=mysql_query($sql,$dbcon) or die(mysql_error());

if($result){
echo "Successful";
echo "<p>";
echo "<a href='p_list_records.php'>View result</a>";

}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}

?>
```

---

Use the following if `mysqli`

```
<?php
include('../connect/connect-mysql.php');

$IDNumber = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $_POST['IDNumber']);
$Power = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $_POST['Power']);
$Power2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $_POST['Power2']);
$Power3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $_POST['Power3']);
$Power4 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $_POST['Power4']);

$sql="UPDATE table SET Power='$Power',Power2='$Power2',Power3='$Power3',Power4='$Power4' WHERE IDNumber='$IDNumber'";
$result=mysqli_query($dbcon,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());

if($result){
echo "Successful";
echo "<p>";
echo "<a href='p_list_records.php'>View result</a>";

}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}

?>
```

To switch to `mysqli_*` connection, replace the `xxx` with your DB credentials.

```
DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'xxx');
DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', 'xxx');
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'xxx');
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'xxx');

$dbcon = @mysqli_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) 
OR die("could not connect");
```

---

**Footnotes:**

`mysql_*` functions deprecation notice:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [**mysqli**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO_MySQL**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also the [**MySQL API Overview**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

These functions allow you to access MySQL database servers. More information about MySQL can be found at » http://www.mysql.com/.

Documentation for MySQL can be found at » http://dev.mysql.com/doc/.

Comment: thanks much for your help, I tried to swap it to msqli_ and it didnt seem to like that .. I'll have to figure out how to swap the whole script set to msqli later, the script is working now though without the sql syntax error.

Comment: Great, am happy to hear it. To close the question as we call it here and be marked as answered, just click the gray outlined White checkmark till it turns Green over to left of my answer @JoJo Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you use the original MySQL-API of PHP you should use mysql_real_escape_string() instead.

```
$IDNumber = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $_POST['IDNumber']);

// ...

$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```